# Maximum percentage of RAM process should used

Tags: memory-management, cpu-usage

**In a nutshell:**

I'm a computational scientist and I have an expensive (CPU-time) simulation to run on a computer cluster.

The most CPU-intensive part of my program is a binary tree structure which is used to accelerate my code. The tree grows as the simulation progresses and the bigger the tree the better the performance boost. I know beforehand how big can my binary tree be before my RAM is full.

**Details:**

The server uses on Red Hat 6.7.

Each node contains:

1. 12 CPUs: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz
2. 64GB of RAM, 8GB of Swap memory

My main part of the code is written in Fortran, while the rest was written in C/C++ - some of the used libraries do not have a Fortran interface. The code is a CFD solver for turbulent reacting flows. I use [Cantera](https://cantera.org/) for the thermodynamic, transport and chemical source terms, [Boost library](https://www.boost.org/) for stiff integrators and then a few Blas/Lapack for matrix operations.

**Question:**

Should I aim to maximize my RAM (say 99% of available memory) or will it affect CPU performance? If so, what's an optimal % of memory use?

Comment: Not a programming question, but perhaps a sysadmin one. It would depend upon the operating system and the computer node used. Read about [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)). Your program runs in virtual memory and has its virtual address space provided by the OS kernel (which manages the RAM)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Should I just delete it and post it on ServerFault? Note I'm just a user of the cluster and don't have any sysadmin privileges

Comment: I would prefer you to improve your question, and explain much more on what cluster and OS you are running, and what is your program doing and in what programming language are you coding (and what libraries are used)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I updated my post with more details about cluster/nodes/code.

Comment: What does "8GB of virtual memory" -on each node- means?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Typo, I meant swap memory

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your cluster is running Linux, since most HPC clusters do.

Your program (actually your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))) is running in its [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), not directly in RAM. The RAM is a resource managed by your OS kernel. Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand more.

You need to avoid [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)).

As a rule of thumb (only), so the details are certainly wrong:

You probably need to ask your system administrator (e.g. because they could be other processes running on the same node, or because he can allocate more resources to you).

If each compute node has some "reasonable" RAM (e.g 128Gbytes or less in 2018), you prefer to not use all of it, and you probably want to consume less than 95% of that if your program is the only one running on that node. Perhaps a few gigabytes of RAM should be left to other things (and to the system).

If you have a compute node with a big lot of RAM (think of a 1Terabyte RAM machine), you might use almost all of it (e.g. 99%) since leaving 10Gbytes for the "rest" might be more than enough.

If you code in C or C++ you could be interested in system calls like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (which is used by `malloc` or `new`), [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html).

In a few cases (related to [locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) of your process), you might have a virtual address space (use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) with [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) to query it) slightly above (e.g. 5% or 10% more) than the used RAM. Be aware of [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size) and of the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). See also [LinuxAteMyRam](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

You certainly need to benchmark and profile.

With your additional edits, I would suggest benchmarking a 50Gbyte run and a 60Gbyte run, and see what is faster. If it is the 60Gbyte one, try 61, then 62Gbytes and perhaps 63Gbytes also.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Some of the concepts you mentioned I knew of but was not familiar with, others (e.g. trashing) are new to me. I'll contact my system admins and see if they can help as well.